# LeaveCriticalSection() yield

Tags: multithreading, winapi, posix

I have two threads that share a critical section. Thread A permanently keeps a lock on the critical section but runs the following code about 50 times per second to give thread B a chance to step in:

```
LeaveCriticalSection(sec);
EnterCriticalSection(sec);
```

Using this code, however, thread B doesn't ever seem to get a chance to acquire the critical section. Instead, the call to EnterCriticalSection(sec) in thread B will block that thread forever, although thread A is unlocking the critical section 50 times per second.

I know that the interval between the calls to LeaveCriticalSection() and EnterCriticalSection() in the 50hz timer in thread A is as brief as it gets, but I'd expect the LeaveCriticalSection() call to yield to other threads waiting on the critical section before continuing execution.

Is LeaveCriticalSection() not supposed to work like this? If so, is there a way to explicitly yield to other threads after releasing the critical section lock? POSIX has something like sched_yield() for that but I think it's not even necessary on POSIX because pthread_mutex_unlock() will give other threads a chance to step in automatically.

But it doesn't seem to work on Windows (or there is something wrong with my code). Can anybody shed some light onto this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does Thread A need to keep the critical section permanently locked?  Why not lock and unlock it like other threads do?

Comment: http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/

Answer (score 3):

Thread A probably needs to yield its timeslice with a `Sleep(0)` or similar call. Critical section operations normally stay in user mode code, so they don't make a transition to the kernel and thus don't give up thread A's timeslice.

Comment: Ok, inserting a Sleep(0) helps but not in an acceptable way because it takes several seconds for thread B to acquire the critical section although it is unlocked 50 times per second in thread A. Is there another way to force an immediate yield?

Comment: To really guarantee that they hand off the way you seem to want you'd need to use a kernel object such as a mutex, or make a signalling mechanism with events.

Comment: Indeed, because since the other thread doesn't get the perks of kernel objects (priority boost meaning immediate wake-up) the only time it has a chance to get the critical section is if there is a context switch between the Leave() and the Enter().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to yield on such a tight loop, you could probably achieve that using [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of critical section (disclaimer: I haven't verified that).